# On touch close AndroidX DialogFragment

Tags: kotlin, androidx, dialogfragment

Any ideas...?
Using import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment, I want to close the dialog when the user touches it. Touch outside dialog closes the dialog (good). I tried

```
dialog!!.setCancelable(true) // no effect
dialog!!.onTouchEvent...// not intuitive solution
```

There is no onClick event and I do not want a button. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want close dialog even you touch inside dialog, you can try this:

```
   class EnsureDialog: DialogFragment() {
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            //you can set onclick with 'view' of this dialog
            view.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
   }
```

And call DialogFragment from another view:

```
    val dialog = EnsureDialog()
    //you can manual set cancelable here:
    //dialog.isCancelable = false
    dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "")
```

Here I'm using kotlin, convert to java if you wan't.
Hope it helpful

Comment: ninhnau19 thank you. The requirement is to touch anywhere on the dialog itself, and this closes the dialog. Yes, touch outside the dialog closes my dialog, but I want any touch on the screen, including on the dialog itself, to close the dialog.

Comment: Hi Shimon, I just updated my answear, you could try.

Comment: It should be as simple as you describe. It does not work though. The onClick event is not firing. Every example I see has a button to close the dialog fragment. That is the designated UX.

Comment: please provide more code about your problem, such as how you create dialog and call it

Comment: THANK YOU!  It was a copy and paste error. When looking at the code I was going to post, I saw I was referencing a different DialogFragment.